# Red5 OflaDemo Missing Java App

Tags: java, red5

I'm trying to run an application on Red5 server. It has the same basic functionality as the bundled demo named `OFLADemo`. So I installed Red5 and was able to see the welcome screen. I installed an app and tried the demo flash and all went well... But when I tried to install that particular application from `/installer` I got stuck with a dialog box with this message:

```
installing oflaDemo-r3989-java6.war
This may take a couple minutes, please wait.
```

Waited for hours instead of minutes, but nothing happened. I was able to get that specific file from google code, but I don't know where to extract/place it.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Im not certain as to why it failed to download and install but you can take the "war" file and rename it to oflaDemo.war and place it within your red5/webapps directory. If the war deployer service is enabled, it will automatically be deployed upon its next directory check (i think the default is every 10 mins). To make sure the war deployer is configured / enabled, open your red5-common.xml file in the red5/conf directory and look for an entry like this:

`<bean id="warDeployService" class="org.red5.server.service.WarDeployer" init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <property name="scheduler" ref="schedulingService"/>
    <property name="checkInterval" value="600000"/>
    <property name="deploymentDirectory" value="${red5.root}/webapps"/>
</bean>`

make sure its not commented out.